# "undefined" message when trying to Display json predefined data on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have   predefined json data  https://www.reddit.com/r/science.json  and i want to display the contents of this data in a html page but th message i get is "undefined'.

My HTML code:

```js
$.getJSON('https://www.reddit.com/r/science.json', function(myDataset) {
  var data = myDataset;
  console.log(data);

  var test2 = data.children[1];

  var data1 = data[0];
  console.log("data1");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Second assignment</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello mama </h1>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

I want to display that data in an array on my web  but i dont understand why i get the undefined message.
Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: `children` is inside oft he object held at `data`, you seem to have forgotten to add `.data` when initializing data: `var data = myDataset.data;`

Comment: For future reference, to debug this type of error, you should understand that `"Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined"` means that you are trying to access property `foo` on `undefined`, in this case `1` is that property meaning `data.children` is undefined. This means that the `.children` property isn't on the `data` object as it is giving `undefined`. As a result, you've misinterpreted what `data` is, and so you can go back to check where you defined it, which at this point you should find that you forgot to add `.data`

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```js
$.getJSON('https://www.reddit.com/r/science.json', function(myDataset) {
  var data = myDataset.data;
  var children = data.children;

  var children0 = children[0];
  console.log("children0", children0);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Second assignment</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello mama </h1>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```